# Javascript function console log

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to `log "test" inside a console` but it's not working. How do I fix this?

I already tried putting the function inside the `draw() function` but it's not working as intended.

```js
let space = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
let x, y, s;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  a = game;
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  fill(0);
  text('X:' + mouseX, 10, 10);
  text('Y:' + mouseY, 10, 20);


  //grid
  x = 100;
  y = 100;
  s = 100;

  fill(200, 0, 0, 0);

  rect(x, y, 300);

  rect(x, y, s);
  rect(x + 100, y, s);
  rect(x + 200, y, s);

  rect(x, y + 100, s);
  rect(x + 100, y + 100, s);
  rect(x + 200, y + 100, s);

  rect(x, y + 200, s);
  rect(x + 100, y + 200, s);
  rect(x + 200, y + 200, s);
  game();
}

function game() {
  if ((mouseX < x) && (mouseX > x + 100) && (mouseY < y) && (mouseY > y + 100)) {
    console.log('test');
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your code itself into the question, instead of a link?

Comment: Yes, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: where do you call the function?

Comment: You don't show us how mouseX is defined or set

Comment: @alex Inside draw()?

Comment: The logic of your if statement is wrong.  the variable mouseX cannot be both less than x and greater than x+100 at the same time.  You'll need to fix that condition for your console.log to ever be hit.

Comment: @AndyRay https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseX

Comment: You have contradictory logical conditions.In general, When `a < b` is `true`, `a>b+100` will be `false`. Since you have `&` (and) operation the result will be `false`.

Comment: @PM77-1   But its p5js?

Comment: @Ergis I called the function I tried putting console.log before the if statement and it worked

Comment: Your `if` expression in `game()` function is guaranteed to always return `false`.  We already explained that twice.

Comment: @PM77-1 oh right, I got my signs the other way